# python virtualenvwrapper TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream'

Tags: centos, pip, virtualenv, python-2.6, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to install virtualenvwrapper on ***CentOS release 6.7 (Final)*** using python 2.6.6 via **pip**:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

then I executed these for adding to .bashrc WORKON_HOME:

```
echo "export WORKON_HOME=~/Env" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

When I try to initialize virtualenvwrapper with this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

I have got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 101, in main
    console = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I found out [here](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issues/274/unexpected-keyword-argument-on-python-26) that this problem was fixed, but the fix  isn't released yet, now I ask, is there a way to fix it manually?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @jhonkola, also solved my problem here.
pip install virtualenvwrapper 4.7.0 must before stevedore 1.9.0, or stevedore will be upgrade to newest version, will be raise logging.NullHandler.
try these to install virtualenvwrapper under python 2.6 env.

`sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper==4.7.0 -U
sudo pip install stevedore==1.9.0 -U`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that virtualenvwrapper 4.7.1 causes this problem, while 4.7.0 works ok. I have also used stevedore 1.9.0, which is the last one with support for python 2.6.

I run these versions on AWS Linux, which should be close to CentOS.